# Are fields $Q[x]/(x^2 -5)$ and $Q[x]/(x^2 + 5)$ isomorphic to each other?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, ring-isomorphism

I am unable to solve this.
My approach was to prove $Q[x]/(x^2 + 5)$ is isomorphic to $Q[k]$ for some `k` and then similarly show it for $Q[x]/(x^2 - 5)$ implying there are both isomorphic to each other.

Comment: Have you entertained the possibility that they may not be isomorphic?

Comment: @AnginaSeng
Ok, if they are not isomorphic then how do I show that? If $Q[x]/(x^2-5)$ is isomorphic to $Q[m]$ for some `m` and if $Q[x]/(x^2 + 5)$ is isomorphic to $Q[n]$ for some `n`, then how do I show that  $Q[n]$ and $Q[m]$ are not isomorphic to each other. One possible approach could be to define a map and conclude towards a contradiction, but I am not able to show it.

Comment: Well, the equation $a^2=5$ is certainly soluble in $\Bbb Q[X]/(X^2-5)$. Is it soluble in $\Bbb Q[X]/(X^2+5)$?

Comment: It is perfectly fine to show that an equation is only soluble in one of the fields. If they were isomorphic, $a^2 = 5$ would imply $\varphi(a^2) = \varphi(5)$, where $\varphi$ is the isomorphism, which implies $\varphi(a)^2 = \varphi(1+\cdots+1) = \varphi(1)+\cdots+\varphi(1) = 1+\cdots+1 = 5$, but then $x^2 = 5$ would also have a solution in the other field.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3720566/are-fields-qx-x2%e2%88%925-and-qx-x25-isomorphic-to-each-other-proof-verifica

Thanks for all your suggestions, I have made a post using your hints and suggestions with the things I am used to. Can you please check if this proof is correct?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: One is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 5]$ whereas the other is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{-5}]$.

Comment: They are fields....

Comment: Right, that part is for $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 2):

They are not isomorphic. One field contains an element $\alpha^2 = -5$ the other does not.

Comment: ... because one field is real

Answer (score 2):

**Hints.**

Set $\alpha=x+ (x^2-5)\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $\beta=x+ (x^2+5)\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

- Justify (if you feel it necessary) that any element of $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-5)$ has the form $a+b\alpha, a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$ (with the usual abuse of notation), while any element of $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+5)$ has the form $a+b\beta, a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$ . This will be handy for computations.
- Let $f:\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-5)\to \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+5)$ be an isomorphism.

Show that $f(\alpha)^2=5$ (again with the usual abuse of notation). Then prove that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+5)$ does not contain any element whose square is $5$.