# Are the fields $\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2−5)$ and $\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2+5)$ isomorphic to each other?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, solution-verification, ring-isomorphism

Thanks for the hints and solutions provided [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3720510/are-fields-qx-x2-5-and-qx-x2-5-isomorphic-to-each-other).

Here is a rigorous proof and a summary to the hints and answers mentioned by others.
Please check if its correct.

$ \mathbb{Q}[x] / (x^2 - 5) $ = {$f(x)  + \langle x^2 - 5\rangle | f(x)\text{ belongs to }\mathbb{Q}[x]$}

Since $ x^2 - 5 = 0 $ (i.e. Zero Coset)

$\implies x^2 - 5 = 0 $

$\implies x^2 = 5 $

$\implies x = \pm \sqrt{5} $

So $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2 - 5)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{5}]$   -- (1)

Similarly $\mathbb{Q}[x] / (x^2 + 5)$ = {$f(x)  + \langle x^2 + 5\rangle | f(x) \text{ belongs to }\mathbb{Q}[x]$}

Since $x^2 + 5 = 0$
$\implies x = \pm \sqrt{5}i $

$\implies \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2 + 5)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{5}, i]$

Since degree of splitting field :

$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5} : \mathbb{Q}] = 2$

$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}, i) : \mathbb{Q}] = 4$

And since the degree of the extension is not same, they are not isomorphic.

If its correct then how can I make it more rigorous?

Comment: You should type properly in the MathJax format. I have changed the title, try applying the same things across your post. Furthermore, as you can see there is a linked question that answers the same thing. Try taking a look at that.

Comment: The linked question is asked by me only. The approach over there is quite different (Here I am using degree of splitting field, there they define isomorphic maps), so I want to know if my proof is correct or not.

Comment: Or simply: For one of these fields $F$, the polynomial $X^2-5\in F[X]$ splits into linear factos, for the other it doesn't

Comment: The degrees are the same

Comment: @lhf Can you please elaborate?

Comment: $x^2+5$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$. So is $x^2-5$.

Comment: $\Bbb{Q}[x]/(x^2 + 5)\cong\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{-5}]\not\cong\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{5},i].$ This approach doesn't work because both fields are degree $2$ over $\Bbb{Q}.$

Comment: I think you should have posted this as an answer to your earlier question. That is a recommended way of getting feedback on your own solution. Now there is a high risk that somebody posts the same answers as somebody else posted to the other question.

Comment: Ok. I will go with the isomorphic map approach then.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  I was not sure if the answer is correct or not. In this case, posting an incorrect answer won't be good on a post I guess.

Comment: There's room for differences of opinion about that. I am mainly worried about duplicate answers appearing.